# Find Network Connectivity using Reachability

Tags: ios, networking, reachability

I have integrated Reachability v2.2 into my App. I just wanted to know that sometimes iPhone is connected to Wifi but there is no internet access. So how can I find this thing ?

Please explain properly anyone who answer this question. I want to show on label that there is Limited or No Connectivity.

Comment: Follow this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083701/how-to-check-for-an-active-internet-connection-on-iphone-sdk)

Answer (score 0):

```
Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"http://google.com"];
NetworkStatus status = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];
```

Comment: In my case when phone is connected to WiFi but internet was not running. I am getting ReachableViaWiFi as NetworkStatus.